# jQuery: How to get parent element properties of dyanmically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I am dynamically creating a list and inputting the list into multiple section elements, however, I want a "data-" property on the **li** elements to have the parent section's **h3** title.  HTML structure is below and my JS I have so far is below as well. If you see in the JS below I am trying to make a variable of **'productTitle'**. This is where I am trying to get the current List's parent's section **h3**.

HTML

```
<div id="GuestMemberTicketsContainer">
    <span class="zInput"><input title="1" data-productattendee="Senior" /></span>
    <span class="zInput"><input title="2" data-productattendee="Senior"/></span>
    <span class="zInput"><input title="3" data-productattendee="Senior"/></span>
    <span class="zInput"><input title="4" data-productattendee="Senior" /></span>

    <span class="zInput"><input title="1" data-productattendee="Adult" /></span>
    <span class="zInput"><input title="2" data-productattendee="Adult"/></span>
    <span class="zInput"><input title="3" data-productattendee="Adult"/></span>
    <span class="zInput"><input title="4" data-productattendee="Adult" /></span>
</div>


<section id="sectionOne">
   <h3>Section One Header</h3>
    <div id="attendeePickerOne" class="picker">
      <!--Dynamic UL get's generated here-->
   </div>
 </section>
 <section id="sectionTwo">
   <h3>Section Two Header</h3>
    <div id="attendeePickerTwo" class="picker">
      <!--Dynamic UL get's generated here-->
   </div>
 </section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/*==============Testing dynamically adding items to list============*/

$("#GuestMemberTicketsContainer .zInput").click(function() {
     var attendeeListMember = $(".picker");
    var list = '<ul class="attendeeList" style="display:table">';

    var itemValue = $(this).find("input").attr("title");
    var attendeeTitle = $(this).find("input").data("productattendee");
    //productTitle is needs to get the list's immediate section H3. 
    var productTitle = $(attendeeListMember).parents("section").find("h3").text();

    for (var i = 0; i < itemValue; i++) {

    $(this).find("input").attr("title") + i + '</li>';
        var li = '<li class="zInput zCheckbox" title="' + attendeeTitle + ' "data-productname="' + productTitle + '"><span class="museumTitle" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">' + attendeeTitle + " " + (i + 1) +
            '<span class="museumPrice" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">7.00</span>' +
            '<span class="museumSubTitle" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Add Ticket</span>' +
            '</li>';

        list += li;
    }


    list += '</div>';
   $(attendeeListMember).append(list);

    //console.log($(finalList).parents("section").find(".titleBar").text());
    //  $(list).zInput();
   });

 });
```

Desired HTML output

```
  <section id="sectionOne">
   <h3>Section One Header</h3>
    <div id="attendeePickerOne" class="picker">
      <ul>
        <li class="zInput zCheckbox" title="Adult1" data-productname="Section One Header">
 <span class="museumTitle" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Adult 1</span>
 <span class="museumPrice" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">7.00</span>
 <span class="museumSubTitle" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Add Ticket</span>
 </li>
  <li class="zInput zCheckbox" title="Adult2" data-productname="Section One Header">
 <span class="museumTitle" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Adult 2</span>
 <span class="museumPrice" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">7.00</span>
 <span class="museumSubTitle" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Add Ticket</span>
 </li>
      </ul>


   </div>
 </section>
 <section id="sectionTwo">
   <h3>Section Two Header</h3>
    <div id="attendeePickerTwo" class="picker">
      <ul>
        <li class="zInput zCheckbox" title="Adult1" data-productname="Section Two Header">
 <span class="museumTitle" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Adult 1</span>
 <span class="museumPrice" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">7.00</span>
 <span class="museumSubTitle" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Add Ticket</span>
 </li>
  <li class="zInput zCheckbox" title="Adult2" data-productname="Section Two Header">
    <span class="museumTitle" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Adult 2</span>
    <span class="museumPrice" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">7.00</span>
    <span class="museumSubTitle" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Add Ticket</span>
 </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: You're missing the '=' after data-productattendee in the first HTML snippet

Comment: You can also go with `$(attendeeListMember).closest("section").find("h3")`, less to select up in tree.

Comment: Do you add same list to all `.picker` elements, or how do you choose where to add the list?

Comment: @skobaljic, I am adding the same list to the .picker.  This is because I have a ticketing webapp ran by JS and HTML that is going to be adding 'Attendees' to multiple events(products) depending on the number of people attending and by their age (Senior, Adult, Child).  The user will then be able to select which attendees will be attending the event. Some of the adults or all of the adults may want to attend, so if the user chooses on the outset there will be 4 adults, they can then choose if only 2 adult will attend the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent node of the "li" element with element.parentNode
Then you can get the text of any node with element.textContent

If you need to select the H3 element, you can use the getElementbyTag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/makes/1/edit?js,console,output)

Approach was to change the event handler to `.change()`, on the `input` itself, and the IDs of the sections matched the data attribute value.

Not sure if this is exactly what you needed as question was a little unclear.

```
$("#GuestMemberTicketsContainer .zInput input").change(function() {

    var list = '<ul class="attendeeList" style="display:table">';

    var itemValue = $(this).attr("title");
    var attendeeTitle = $(this).data("productattendee");
    //productTitle is needs to get the list's immediate section H3. 
    var productTitle = $("#"+attendeeTitle).find('h3').text();

    for (var i = 0; i < itemValue; i++) {

    $(this).attr("title") + i + '</li>';
        var li = '<li class="zInput zCheckbox" title="' + attendeeTitle + ' "data-productname="' + productTitle + '"><span class="museumTitle" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">' + attendeeTitle + " " + (i + 1) +
            '<span class="museumPrice" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">7.00</span>' +
            '<span class="museumSubTitle" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">Add Ticket</span>' +
            '</li>';

        list += li;

    }

    console.log(attendeeTitle, productTitle)

    list += '</div>';

   $("#"+attendeeTitle).find('ul').remove();
   $("#"+attendeeTitle).append(list);

 });
```